# What if + past simple or past participle

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, past-participles

I always come across this kind of sentences. What kind of conditonal should I use when I want to talk about the "possible result of an imagined situation in the past".

I don't understand why we don't use ***past perfect*** in these sentences since these sentences questioning something that was might or might not have been in the past. These questions refer to the past.

As far as I understand American speakers don't usually use "past perfect" in conditional sentences, even though those sentences refer to the past. They just use past simple. Am I right?

> 1-What if she ***did find*** a life at that convent ? (The subject doesn't
>   know if she found a life at that convent or not . This action of
>   "finding a life" happened or didn't happen in the past so the subject
>   is just curious about it right now . Because the subject is
>   investigating a crime right now )
>
> 2-What if they ***wanted*** to protect her ? (The subject doesn't know if
>   they wanted to protect her or not in the past. The subject is just
>   curious about it right now . Because the subject is investigating a
>   crime right now. )

I think these sentences should be like this:

> 1'- What if she ***had found*** a life at that convent?
>
> 2'- What if they ***had wanted*** to protect her?

Comment: There is no way of knowing if anything is implied or not without further context. If I'm writing a novel, for instance, and I'm debating what to do with a character, I easily may not yet have written what happens to them. In the case of these questions, I could simply be brainstorming different possibilities and outcomes. In this completely hypothetical situation, however, the actual language would remain the same as if I were using it in a situation where something actually *had* happened—and even if I actually knew what that was.

Answer (score 1):

As an American speaker, I think you are correct.  1 and 2 sound fine.  1' implies she did not find a life at the convent.  2' sounds like we are trying to figure out the motivation of something "they" did in the past.

Comment: Thank you. When we use this sentence "What if she had found a life at that convent? " , I imply she didn't find a life at that convent? It doesn' fit into the context I gave since the man asking this question don't know if she found a life or not. 

So here using past simple: " What if she did find a life at that convent? " sounds okay even though it refers to the past possible event not present time or future?

Comment: In the context you give, it might be better to say "What if she found a life at that convent?"  You could also say "What if she did find a life at that convent?" but that has a little extra emphasis on "did".  It might make more sense in these cases:

"Let's say she didn't find a life at that convent.  That would be bad.  But, what if she did find a life at that convent?"

or

"What if she did find a life at that convent?  So what?  What's wrong with that?"